# How to connect a CloudFormation Template with a Lambda Function that creates a new database on an Aurora PostgreSQL Instance in RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I hope you can help!

**Goal**

I am trying to configure the following szenario on AWS:

1. In AWC CLI: Call [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) Template to create a new stack.
2. In Template: Call [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) Function.
3. In Lambda Function: Connect to [Aurora PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraPostgreSQL.html) Instance in [RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) via [pg](https://node-postgres.com/) module.
4. In PostgresSQL: Create a new database.

**Short story**

As soon as I add my Lambda Function to the default VPC it is not able anymore to send a response back to CloudFormation and the stack gets stuck in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`. It works when I delete the VPC from the configuration of the Lambda function. But then I can not connect to another component like the RDS database instance anymore. How to deal with this?

**Long story**

*To make it work my first step was to manually connect to PostgreSQL and create a new database:*

1. Configured the Default Security Group to allow ALL Inbound and ALL Outbound traffic. No worries, only for testing. I will change that later.
2. Added the Security Group to the RDS Instance to accept traffic from and to other components within the same VPC. Necessary for step 3.
3. Created a [Cloud9](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/welcome.html) Environment to have access to a terminal in the VPC. Connecting to the PostgreSQL Database and creating a database works!

*Now my goal was to create a new database via a Lambda function:*

1. Manually created a new Lambda Function including a new role with basic Lambda authorization. Also added `AdministratorAccess` to the role. No worries, again only for testing. The Lambda function runs on Node.js 12.x with a 15 seconds timeout.
2. Packed my Lambda script and the pg module in a zip File and uploaded it. The script looks like this:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    var databaseName = event.DatabaseName;
    var dbSuperUser = event.DBSuperUser;
    var dbSuperPassword = event.DBSuperPassword;

    const dbClient = new Client({
        host: "<Database Instance Endpoint>",
        port: 5432,
        database: "postgres",
        user: dbSuperUser,
        password: dbSuperPassword
    });

    await dbClient.connect();
    await dbClient.query("CREATE DATABASE " + databaseName);
    await dbClient.end();

    var response = {status: 'SUCCESS'};
    return response;
};
```

3. Calling the Lambda script from Cloud9 via `aws lambda invoke` leads to a timeout. This was expected behaviour because the Lambda function is not in the same VPC as the RDS Database Instance yet.
4. Added the default VPC with the three default Subnets and the Default Security Group to the Lambda Function configuration. And voila, the database gets created! We are on track.

*Now I tried to call the Lambda function and create the database from a basic CloudFormation Template:*

1. Created the template including a [Custom Ressource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html):

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters": {
        "DatabaseName": {"Type": "String"}
    },
    "Resources": {
        "SampleInstance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "InstanceType": "t1.micro",
                "ImageId": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["CreateDatabase", "Id"]}
            }
        },
        "CreateDatabase": {
            "Type": "Custom::CreateDatabase",
            "Properties": {
                "ServiceToken": "<Lambda Function ARN>",
                "DBSuperUser": "<DBSuperUser>",
                "DBSuperPassword": "<DBSuperPassword>",
                "DatabaseName": {"Ref": "DatabaseName"}                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The EC2 Instance is just an example and will fail to create anyway because the ImageId will not be valid. It is just there to test if I get a response from the Lambda function.

2. Changed the Lambda function to receive the event from CloudFormation and send back a response. I could use the [cfc-response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html) module but decided to copy it's code to my Lambda function to see what is going on under the hood. Please click the link above and scroll down to *Module Source Code* to see the source code.

Also I changed getting the input parameters like this:

```
var customerName = event.ResourceProperties.CustomerName;
var dbSuperUser = event.ResourceProperties.DBSuperUser;
var dbSuperPassword = event.ResourceProperties.DBSuperPassword;
```

And sending the response to CloudFormation like this:

```
responseData = {Id: '1234567890'};
send(event, context, SUCCESS, responseData);
```

3. Running the template via AWS CLI command `aws cloudformation create-stack` causes the stack being stuck in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`. But the database gets successfully created!
4. As soon as I remove the VPC configuration from the Lambda function the problem is gone. CloudFormation succesfully receives the response from the function and tries to create the EC2 Sample Instance. But now the Lambda function can not access RDS anymore to create the database.

*This leads to the following questions:*

- Does the VPC configuration in the Lambda function causes a problem with the connection to the CloudFormation template?
- If yes, how do I fix this?
- Is the network configuration the right place to look? Or do I have to change my coding?

*Other things I have checked:*

- I compared the following variables and objects of the Lambda script in both runs (successful and failed response): `event`, `context`, `responseBody`, `parsedUrl`, `options`, `request`. They are identical (except certain Ids etc.).

Looking forward to your thoughts on this!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is a simple Lambda, and doesn't report its status as required by a [CloudFormation custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). So first step is to ensure that you're following the requirements.

If you are, and your code is getting blocked when reporting status back to S3, then the most likely cause is that you're running in a subnet that has neither a [NAT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat.html) nor an [S3 endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html). If you don't otherwise need a NAT, the S3 endpoint is free so would be the best solution. If you do already have a NAT, ensure that the Lambda runs in a subnet where the NAT is available.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! Creating an S3 endpoint worked for me.

Comment: Some additional information:

An async function like this `exports.handler = async (event, context) => { ...` and using `await` didn't work for me.

I had to declare the handler function like this `exports.handler = function (event, context) { ...` and use promises like this `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ...;` and this `.then( ...` to make it work